# Posting a form with control characters

Tags: javascript, forms, control-characters

I'm puzzled by finding out that newer version of Chrome, Opera and Safari don't allow control characters in text inside INPUT elements. In fact, characters like  `\1`, `\x02`, `\b` etc. are simply interpreted as string terminators.

```
var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.value = 'Hello\x02 World!';
alert('input.value is "' + input.value + '" (' + input.value.length + ' chars)');
```

The code above only outputs 5 characters on Chrome, Opera and Safari.

Firefox and IE do not show this behavior/bug/security feature or whatever. Now my question is how would you post a form containing those special characters in plain Javascript, in a way that works in all browsers?

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nkx4n/

Comment: As far as I can tell, the part that's broken is the <INPUT> element, so you cannot get those characters into the form in the browsers that interpret it as a string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in chrome and, like you, if i try to asign to the input a string with \ in it, it stop, but there is no problem if the user enter it in the input directly, like you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2JVU/1/)

```
    myP.innerHTML = "Length is: " + myInput.value.length + " chars" + "; text is: " + myInput.value;
```

I don't know if you need to set the value in code but if you don't there shouldn't be any problem because the user can still enter it and it's read.